# How to float elements inside a div with layout = row/column in angular material?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using the following code to arrange two div blocks in a row

```
 <div layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row" layout-align="center center" id="row">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
</div>
```

css goes like this

```
#row div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

I want to make it responsive such than on small screens, it rearranges to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhnBM.png)

How can I achieve this in Angular material?
I tried doing this by using

```
#b {
     float: left !important;
  }
```

but it seems like float doesn't work inside layout container.

Here's the [demo](https://codepen.io/ayushgosi/pen/NdPQBW)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix flex layout with `float`. You can use angular-material's `flex-order` to do this. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children

```
<div flex-order="1">a</div>
<div flex-order="0" flex-order-gt-xs="2">b<br/>(pull it to the left)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place #b before #a in your mark up, and then float #a left, #b right. You can then remove this in @media query if needed.

Or you could use flexbox...